# Is all I need the "identity url"? - OpenID

Tags: python, django, authentication, openid, google-openid

I'm just wondering if all I need is the identity url in order to to theoretically attach an OpenID account to a user's account.

I have identity urls that look like the following: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=YGnyuGHMUmhUI98nuhUMhu98nuN.

Is this different between OpenID 1.0 and 2.0?

Just in case someone asks: I'm using Django + [django-openid-consumer](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-consumer/)

Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to bind to a user account is the "Claimed Identifier" which is what the sample URL you provided is called.  OpenID 1.x and 2.0 have a handful of URLs it deals with, including "openid.identity" and "openid.claimed_id" values.  It is *very* important that you're reading from the property that gives you `openid.claimed_id` rather than `openid.identity` when storing the value with the user account.  In the case of Google as you showed, the same value is put into both parameters so it's hard to know for sure whether you're getting the right thing from the OpenID library you're using.

Just review what Django offers to you, and if you see anything that looks like claimed_id, use that.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to get the claimed_id from Google in lightopenID implementation in PHP?
I'm doing this - `echo $openid->claimed_id`
Doesn't help.